# Android: ProgressDialog does not animate when first called

Tags: android, webview, progressdialog

I have the loadWebView method below...

```
private void loadWebView() {
    final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    myWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Connecting...", true);
    myWebView.loadUrl(_Host);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Could not connect.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            initSettings();
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,
                                              HttpAuthHandler handler,
                                              String host,
                                              String realm) {
            handler.proceed(_Username, _Password);
        }
        //@Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
                                       SslErrorHandler handler,
                                       SslError error) {
            handler.proceed();
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
        {
            pd.show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Progress dialog does not animate when first called from the main activity in a cellphone (galaxy nexus) but it does on a tablet.
Also in the nexus, when the surfing starts it animates ok.

Any ideas? everything else works ok!

EDIT (SOLVED)
ok I found the solution. On initSettings method I was called the WebView with these attributes...

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
myWebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
myWebView.loadUrl = "about:blank";
```

I moved it onReceivedError and everything is ok now!

```
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        view.loadUrl("about:blank");
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Could not connect.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        initSettings();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call to loadUrl after configure your WebViewClient, in other case you might not use the webviewclient at all:

```
 myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { ..}
 myWebView.loadUrl(_Host);
```

And yes, the behaviour is unpredictable!. It may or may not work if you use the wrong order.